# Indexing Error with HDU FITS file format with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, astronomy, fits, astropy

I'm attempting to read the data from a FITS file using the `astropy` module `fits` and then standard numpy array handling. However, for some reason I am receiving the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hdulist = fits.open('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/spec-1959-53440-0605.fits')
hdu     = hdulist[1]
data    = hdu.data
flux    = data[:, 1]
```

^ Error Traceback to the `flux = data[:, 1]` line.

```
loglam  = data[:, 2]
```

This may be a question that perhaps astronomers could answer (or, specifically, astronomers familiar with `.fits` files from the SDSS), but I welcome the input from numpy and python users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just had the following answer from the SDSS help desk:

Replace:

```
flux   = data[:,0]
loglam = data[:,1]
```

with

```
flux   = data['flux']
loglam = data['loglam']
```

This is the correct way to access fields in a Numpy record array.

Comment: If this works, it's probably a good idea to go ahead and accept your own answer.

Comment: I can only do this in 2 days time, apparently.

Comment: It looks like `data` is a `BinTableHDU`, not an `ImageHDU`, which is why using multiple indices failed.  If you look at the `repr` of the object, it will show you that there are multiple `dtypes`: `dtype=[('flux', '>f4'), ('loglam', '>f4'), ('ivar', '>f4'), ('and_mask', '>i4'), ('or_mask', '>i4'), ('wdisp', '>f4'), ('sky', '>f4'), ('model', '>f4')]`.  You can also use `data.dtype.names`

Comment: It may be useful, if you're not sure what's going on with a FITS file, to use `hdulist.info()` to print basic statistics on the file, you would then find that this is a table not a basic array.  And as @keflavich mentioned above if you print the data array itself you can also see that it is a table (or multi-field array).  See also http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/table.html#table-data-as-a-record-array

Comment: FWIW I also submitted a slight edit to your answer to clarify that the column-name indexing is the correct way to access fields in a multi-field Numpy array.